# `PG::CONNECTIONBad: FATAL: role "my_username" does not exist` BUT "my_username" is listed as a user in psql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I enter "psql" then "\du" into the terminal, I see that "my_username" is listed with superuser and createdb abilities. However, when I try to run rake db:create, I get an error that "my_username" doesn't exist.

Some important background: I am running rails through the Ubuntu sub-system on Windows. My project is stored on my Dropbox so that I can work on it on both of my laptops. I had an issue getting psql set up on my first laptop as well, but the issue in the end was that I needed to remove psql from the ubuntu command line (`sudo apt-get remove postgresql`) and it was able to correctly look for the version on my windows. I additionally had to specify in my database.yml that the host was localhost. It now works perfectly on my first laptop, and I'm able to create new apps or clone apps from git and create dbs as long as I add the `host: localhost` line to the database.yml.

I can't seem to figure out how to fix the issue on this laptop, I've already removed psql from the command line in Ubuntu and I have the same psql version downloaded to my windows. Is anybody familiar with Linux for Windows Subsystem and getting psql set up? I suspect that the linux instance of psql isn't aligning with what my project is running in my Windows c:/ drive but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: identifier in postgresql are case sensitive, but in many contexts unless care is taken case is folded to lowercase. are there any capital letters in the parts you have hidden?

Comment: @Jasen no, they're the exact same. I think my psql in Ubuntu is connecting to a different instance than Windows but I don't know how to check or correct.

Comment: if you use the same IP address and port for the database connection it should be the same.